# Python: What's the use case for set.pop()?

Tags: python

The Python built-in type `set` has a method called [pop()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.pop), from the docs:

> Remove and return an arbitrary element from the set. Raises KeyError
>   if the set is empty.

I couldn't think of any use case for this feature, it seems to be an attempt to implement the `list` interface.

Why is this part of the Python standard?

Comment: It is a mirror of [`dict.pop()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) and [`dict.popitem()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem), actually. It is used in situations where you need a 'next' value to process but order is not required.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'd use it when you have a pool of jobs to process in no particular order. Jobs should only be executed once, but once executed can be added again:

```
jobs = {job1, job2, job3}

while jobs:
    job = jobs.pop()
    job.process()
```

where `job.process()` potentially adds more jobs to the pile. Once all jobs have been processed, the set will be empty and the loop is done.

Or, for a less contrived, real-world example, see the [`DependencyFinder.find()` method](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/src/207d4599a330913d51a4c5865745a49e11e851cb/distlib/locators.py#lines-1192:1300) from the `distlib` library (used by `pip`, for example), which uses a `todo` set to track distribution providers that still need processing.

The method is a mirror of the [`dict.popitem()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem), which explicitly mentions set algorithms:

> `popitem()` is useful to destructively iterate over a dictionary, as often used in set algorithms.

Before `set` was added to the language, you'd use a dictionary with `None` values to emulate  a set.

Comment: This seems like a very contrived example. In most cases it seems unlikely that there wouldn't be a prefered order. Also, it seems unlikely that you'd only want to dedup the queued jobs. A more realistic scenario would probably have a queue of pending jobs, and a set of executed jobs so that a single job was never executed twice.

Comment: @branks: this is not nearly as far-fetched as you think it is. The [`distlib` library](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/src/af1107909f4dffd7f474773e1f3aca3616ff9ba1/distlib/locators.py?at=default#cl-1134) uses sets exactly like this, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are making a solver for a guessing game (e.g. Wordle).  It could start with a set of all possible answers. The algorithm would then be:

repeat until game over:

1. Use pop() to get a new word to try.  The order doesn't really matter (there are more elegant algorithms but this is just a simple example).
2. Based on the clues, remove any words in the set that are invalid.